# View Binding Both Activity and Bottom Bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

I am setting up View Binding in my project, and I ran into an issue. I tried to [look for documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) regarding this under without luck.

I have my activity, and I have set up View Binding for this:

```
class AeropressActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAeropressBinding
    private lateinit var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<ConstraintLayout>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAeropressBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        setupBottomSheet()
        onClickListeners()

    }
      private fun setupBottomSheet() {
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.layout_bottom_sheet))

        // OnClickListener for bottomSheetBehavior
        bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(
            object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                }

                override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                    
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

After setting this up, I want to use View Binding for my `BottomSheet`, as it has some buttons and a Chronometer that I want to add `onClickListeners` to.

I have added the

```
lateinit var bindingBottomSheet: LayoutBottomSheetBinding
```

but inflating this does nothing:

```
bindingBottomSheet = LayoutBottomSheetBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

**What am I missing to get this to work? Is this even possible?**

Edit:

The BottomSheet layout looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
    tools:context=".BottomSheetActivity"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/background_bottom_bar"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_button_home"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_button_timer"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_stopwatch"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image_view_button_home"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/image_view_button_info"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
        android:id="@+id/image_view_button_info"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/image_view_button_timer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_bottom_reset"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Reset"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view_button_info" />

    <Chronometer
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:format="%s"
        android:id="@+id/chronometer_bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="6dp"
        android:paddingEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button_bottom_start"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button_bottom_reset"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view_button_timer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_bottom_start"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_bottom_stop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_view_button_home" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_bottom_stop"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Stop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_bottom_start" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you need another ViewBinding for the BottomBar? You should be able to get a reference to the bottom bar from the activity's view binding. Something like binding.bottomBar

Comment: The BottomSheet has its own layout which is added to the activity's layout by using the <include layout = "@layout/...">. This is because there I have multiple activities which reuse the layout_bottom_sheet.

Comment: Can you share how layout looks like of the `BottomSheet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The BottomSheet has its own layout which is added to the activity's layout by using the .

> I want to use View Binding for my BottomSheet, as it has some buttons and a Chronometer that I want to add onClickListeners to.

So, you can't access the underlying views of the BottomSheet from the `AeropressActivity`

- First make sure that the `BottomSheet` layout is wrapped in `<layout></layout>` tag.
- Then make sure to have an id to the `<include>` so that it allows you access the `BottomSheet` layout using data binding.

`AeropressActivity` layout:

```
<layout>
    .
    .
    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</layout>
```

Then to access buttons in the `BottomSheet` layout:

```
bindingBottomSheet.bottomSheet.myButtonId
```

Assuming that the button id is: `my_button_id`

Comment: That totally works! Thank you so much for your help. The solution was very elegant and easy.